# I don't understand PHP references

Tags: php, reference

```php
<?
$map = [];
$cur = null;

function write ($s) {
    global $cur;
    $cur[] = $s;
}

function set_cursor ($key) {
    global $map, $cur;
    $cur = [];
    $map [$key] = &$cur;
}

set_cursor ("key_a");
write ("Hello");
write ("World");

set_cursor ("key_b");
write ("Foobar");

var_dump ($map);

?>
```

From languages I am familiar with (Javascript, C#, C) I expected `$map` to contain

```
{
    "key_a": ['Hello', 'World'],
    "key_b": ['Foobar']
}
```

Instead it contains

```
{
    "key_a": ['Foobar'],
    "key_b": ['Foobar']
}
```

This seems unintuitive. How do I need to modify the code to return the expected result?

As per request in the comments, here is the equivalent code in Javascript that produces the desired and expected result:

```js
var map = {};
var cur = null;

function set_cursor (key) {
    cur = [];
    map [key] = cur;
}

function write (s) {
    cur.push (s);
}

set_cursor ("key_a");
write ("Hello");
write ("World");

set_cursor ("key_b");
write ("Foobar");

console.log(map);
```

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem. 1. You can't redeclare `_()` function. If that really is your code, it must be showing errors. 2. Rename `_()` to another function name get this result: `array (size=1)
  7 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'Hello' (length=5)
      1 => string 'World' (length=5)

D:\wwwroot\_mytools\hot-test\hot-test.php(8) : eval()'d code:23:
array (size=2)
  7 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'Foobar' (length=6)
  255 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'Foobar' (length=6)
`

Comment: @vee `_()` only exists if you enable the gettext extension.

Comment: Yes, I'm enabled gettext and it's showing re-declare error. You can't re declare the same function name that is already exists in PHP.

Comment: @vee To run this code, either disable gettext or create an ad-hoc namespace like `namespace Example;`. The function name, albeit arguably confusing, is not the problem here.

Comment: That is my code and it runs just fine just not producing the results that I want...

Comment: I think it'd be helpful to see a JavaScript snippet that implements this. Variable scope is rather different, there's no concept to mapping global variables to local variables, there aren't references like in PHP. The PHP snippet alone is so convoluted and obfuscated that it's hard to say what it's meant to do.

Comment: What do you not understand about the code? I honestly don't know how I can make it any clearer.

Comment: I have added Javascript code as requested.

Comment: Sorry that I can't explain but you need to send reference value between functions. Here is the class I create and tested. The result is same as you want. ( http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5fbd6b7c2c3f2b6c61de4b525593f2ebb63a4735 )

Comment: Thank you but I really need the code to work as a script not as a class. and $cur must be able to point to arbitrary arrays that could be nested deeper than one level.

Comment: It looks pretty obvious to me that this is not working as expected, as the second part of your algorithm still accesses the first `$cur`  array. This can be inspected by dumping `$map` before the second call of `set_cursor`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK I have figured it out myself in the meanwhile. In typical PHP fashion, you had to use some non-sensical arcane constructs to get it working. In particular you had to use `$GLOBALS` instead of `global` to get it to produce the same results that would be produced by any other language.

Here's the code:

```php
<?
$map = [];
$cur = null;

function write ($s) {
    global $cur;
    $cur[] = $s;
}

function set_cursor ($key) {
    global $map;
    if (array_key_exists ($key, $map) == false)
        $map[ $key] = [];
    $GLOBALS["cur"] = &$map[ $key ];
}

set_cursor ("key_a");
write ("Hello");
write ("World");

set_cursor ("key_b");
write ("Foobar");

set_cursor ("key_a");
write ("Hello");
write ("Again");

set_cursor ("key_b");
write ("Bazqux");

var_dump ($map);
?>
```

Comment: If you want to use references, just do that - there's no need to use `global`  for this

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. If there is an easier way to achieve this, can you please post it as an answer.

Comment: Usually, you would use `&`  for references, not global variables

Comment: Well I need a global reference. Surely there should be nothing wrong with that? If you have a better solution that produces the desired result as outlined in the original question, please do post it.

Comment: It's normal to get different implementations for different features. Your JavaScript variables aren't themselves global, they're properties of an object defined in an outer scope (`window` in browsers, the global object in Node) and such scope in available in inner blocks, but PHP scope works differently (no nested scopes). JavaScript doesn't have references at all. And (this doesn't apply here but it's worth mentioning) JavaScript arrays are objects (thus passed by reference) but PHP are not (they're passed by value). Using a language to code in another always leads to frustration.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a class to acheive this.

```php
class Map
{
    private array $map = [];
    private string $cur = '';
    
    public function write(string $s): static 
    {
        $this->map[$this->cur][] = $s;
        return $this;
    }
    
    public function setCursor(string $key): static
    {
        $this->cur = $key;
        return $this;
    }
    
    public function getMap(): array 
    {
        return $this->map;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```php
$map = new Map();

$map->setCursor('key_a');
$map->write('Hello');
$map->write('World');

$map->setCursor('key_b');
$map->write('Foobar');

// or in fluent style :

$map->setCursor('key_a')
    ->write('Hello')
    ->write('Again')
    ->setCursor('key_b')
    ->write('Bazqux');

// display
var_dump($map->getMap());
```

output

```
array(2) {
  ["key_a"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "Hello"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "World"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "Hello"
    [3]=>
    string(5) "Again"
  }
  ["key_b"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "Foobar"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "Bazqux"
  }
}
```

Demo (PHP 8.1) : https://3v4l.org/de6tv#v8.1.1

Comment: But why should I have to use a class for this? This seems wholly unnecessary.

Comment: For many reasons ! 1. Because it doesn't use globals (bad practice). 2. Because it doesn't need to use references (may be difficult to maintain). 3. It could be reusable. 4 It could be overloaded. 5. etc...

Comment: I'd just like to add that the JavaScript code (esp. the original version with single letter function names) has vibes of being a port from C. PHP has mostly evolved as OOP, heavily influenced by Java, so writing procedural code is certainly not what it's best suited for.